# Trigger javascript on initial page load, NOT on pressing 'Back' button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript which is being executed when the page is loaded. When a visitor proceeds to the next page and clicks on the "Back" button of his browser I do not want the javascript to be triggered again.

The javascript hides some div's.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
some code
});
```

Comment: you have one way to disable the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link about controlling Back button events with Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript) has a few solutions to detect the event, such as setting a slightly different URL (one with a parameter that your onload script can read.